# How to hide asp:literal after refreshing page

Tags: asp.net, literals

I have asp:literal text line which will shown after pressed "Save" button.
But when i refresh site, the literal text won't disappear.

```
<asp:Literal id="Literall" Text="" runat="server"/>
Literall.text="Save completed!!!"
```

Comment: How i can configure that with refresh? Only with that, the whole text won't be printed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jcherryhomes.com/post/2013/01/03/Twitter-Bootstrap-Alert-Using-WebForms.aspx) site!
There is explained everything about your problem.

Comment: Kiitos, tiesin että sinulta löytyy vastaus!

Comment: Ei kestä :) Oli ilo auttaa